# What is the difference between kenx JS and Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

What is the difference between kenxjs and sequeilize if I want to use MySQL as a database in my node js application?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028287/how-is-node-js-knex-similar-different-to-sequelize

Answer (score 0):

Knex is just a query builder while Sequelize is an ORM. So Knex just simplifies the proccess of building SQL-queries for you and in Sequelize first of all you define models that are corresponding to your tables and associations between them and after that you work through this models and not with plain SQL. Sequelize makes you think in terms of domain models and not just SQL-queries.